# Making a bot that sends messages evey 40 minutes Discord.py

Tags: python, timer, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make a bot that pings (ping role) every 40 minutes to general channel. For example at the start of 40 minutes saying @ping role.The bot doesn't seem to work since nothing appears in my text channel.

My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
client.remove_command("help")

target_channel_id = 869727547221475388

@client.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def help(ctx):
    em = discord.Embed(title = "Help", description = "Use !help <command>. for extended information on a command.",color = ctx.author.color)

    em.add_field(name = "Moderation", value = "kick,ban,unban,warn,clear5")
    em.add_field(name = "Activities", value = "test, message,Games_With_Friends,FlashBang,SB")
    

    await ctx.send(embed = em)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@tasks.loop(hours=0.02777778)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def ping_start():
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(target_channel_id)
    print(f"Got channel {message_channel}")
    await message_channel.send("ctx.message.guild.ping_role")

@ping_start.before_loop
async def before():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")

ping_start.start()

client.run("Token")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have assigned `discord.Bot` object to `client` variable but still you are trying to access that through `bot` variable at some places.
Then to ping a role you have to get the role by role ID.

Following code should work.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO,
)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

target_channel_id = 869727547221475388
role_id = #write role ID here
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@tasks.loop(minutes=40)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def ping_start():
    message_channel = client.get_channel(target_channel_id)
    role = message_channel.guild.get_role(role_id)
    print(f"Got channel {message_channel}")
    await message_channel.send(role.mention)

@ping_start.before_loop
async def before():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")

ping_start.start()

client.run("TOKEN")
```